# Python Kivy in Eclipse IDE on Mac

Tags: python, eclipse, frameworks, ide, kivy

I am trying to use the Kivy library for python in the Eclipse IDE. I have tried some solutions that I have found on google but none of them seem to work. I am using Mac OSX 10.7 with python 2.7.

I have installed the kivy setup.py file with the command

```
python setup.py install
```

I now how a kivy folder in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/. In eclipse I go to Preferences->PyDev->Interpreter and where I can add libraires I add that path and apply the changes. When writing python code I can now import everything I need from kivy without error and write code with code completion using the kivy modules. When I try to run the project with the code,

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class PongGame(Widget):
    pass

class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return PongGame()


if __name__=='__main__':
    PongApp().run()
```

I get the error, [image: kivy python error]

How can I setup eclipse so I do not get this error and I can run Kivy programs straight from eclipse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a recent [Google Groups post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pygame-mirror-on-google-groups/PwRRPuNe1pg), Russell Owen outlined how he built a 64-bit version of [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org) 1.9.1 for Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard), and also provides a URL to a [pre-built 64-bit PyGame OS X binary dmg](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/python/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg) file!

[pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/python/pygame-1.9.1release-py2.7-python.org-macosx10.6.dmg)

Russell's instructions were:

```
Building pygame 1.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.6 using XCode 3.2.6
2012-04-12
I was building this for a binary distribution that would run against python.org's 64-bit Python 2.7.2, for use on Mac OS X 10.6 and later.

* Install dependencies:

- libjpeg (use ./configure, make, sudo make install)
- SDL and extra packages (use precompiled framework builds):
  - SDL
  - SDL_mixer
  - SDL_image
  - SDL_ttf
- portmidi (use CMake as per the instructions)

* Delete shared libraries in /usr/local/lib (if you want to build a binary installer that can be used elsewhere).

* Check for /usr/local/lib/portmidi.a and if not found, make it a symlink from /usr/local/lib/portmidi_s.a or whatever portmidi got installed.

* Modify config_darwin.py to include '/usr/X11/include' and '/usr/X11/lib':
    incdirs = ['/usr/X11/include', '/usr/local/include']
    libdirs = ['/usr/X11/lib/', '/usr/local/lib']

(since libpng and libfreetype are standard in /usr/X11)

* Configure pygame and make sure it finds everything:

python config.py

As of 2012-04-12 on Mac OS X 10.6 I found that png was NOT found. I have no idea why, but I went ahead and installed it manually.

Also SCRAP is not found, but apparently that is normal for Mac OS X.

* Build pygame normally

python setup.py build
bdist_mpkg (or sudo python setup.py install if you don't want a binary installer)
```

Hopefully, these instructions will work on more recent versions of OS X and XCode (please let us know if they do).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the import errors in your output it would appear you need to install pygame and PIL.

The pygame install looks tricky but there's a guide for installing pygame with homebrew:

https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/issue/82/homebrew-on-leopard-fails-to-install#comment-627494

If you have Xcode installed you should in theory be able to do 'easy_install PIL' or 'pip install PIL' if you're using distribute.

Comment: darn. pygame does not work with 64 bit python. I would have to install the 32-bit python and I do not want to do that. Guess I will not be using Kivy.

Comment: @JakeRunzer Go-ahead and have a look at the info in my [post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14195232/304330) , looks like 64-bit Mac PyGame compilation issues might have been solved ;-) . Cheers.